# Selecting first and last elements of an array in one line

Tags: arrays, ruby

My task is to select the highest and lowest numbers from an array. I think I've got a good idea what I want to do, but just struggling to access the information in the right format to meet the pass criteria.

```
def high_and_low(numbers)
  array = numbers.split(" ").map! {|x| x.to_i}
  array.sort! {|a,b| b <=> a}
  puts array[0, -1]
end
```

Numbers might have looked like `"80 9 17 234 100"`, and to pass, I need to output `"9 234"`. I was trying `puts array.first.last`, but have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 13):

There is the [`Array#minmax`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax) method that does exactly what you need:

```
array = [80, 9, 17, 234, 100]
array.minmax
#=> [9, 234]
```

Usage in the context of your `high_and_low` method that takes the input and returns the result as strings:

```
def high_and_low(numbers)
  numbers.split.              # `split` splits at whitespaces per default
          map(&:to_i).        # does the same as `map { |x| x.to_i }`
          minmax.             # extracts min and max
          reverse.            # reverses order to maxmin
          join(' ')           # joins min and max with a whitespace
end

high_and_low('80 9 17 234 100')
#=> "234 9"
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I forgot to mention I had to post the max value then min, I ultimately used array.minmax.reverse.join. Why is it not possible to use [0, -1]?

Comment: @EatsIndigo : Because the `[]` method does not accept multiple arguments, but `values_at` does: `array.values_at(0, -1)` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to just use `min` and `max`:

```
numbers = "80 9 17 234 100"
array = numbers.split(' ').map(&:to_i)
[array.min, array.max] #=> [9, 234]
```

Your solution is pretty good if the criteria was something that didn't have a built in function.

Comment: Thanks, I ultimately had to use:

    def high_and_low(numbers)
      array = numbers.split(" ").map! {|x| x.to_i}
      return array.minmax.reverse.join(" ")
    end

Thanks for your help.

Bleh, formatting issues

Comment: Which solution did you finally use?

Answer (score 0):

If you want no commas try:

```
array.minmax.join(' ')
```